How to improve focal length accuracy in camera calibration?
Issue
I am working on calibrating some cameras, and I'm having slight (5% or so) error in the focal length, as well as okay but not great re-projection error (~0.7px). For my application, I need the accuracy to be as close to perfect as possible, so this is too much error.
The focal length I am getting from calibration is 2530 px. I am using this camera. Based off the resolution of (4056, 3040), the pixel size of 1.55 um and the H-FoV of 75 degrees, I can calculate my expected focal length to be 4.096558636989045 mm, or 2642.9410561219647 px.
Focal Length Experiment
To verify that this expected focal length is correct, I have set up an experiment to measure the focal length. With the camera focused, I set up a chaurco board perpendicular to my camera, and measured the depth. Then, I measured a section of the board in the image, and I of course know how big this is in mm based on my board dimensions. Using the pinhole camera model, I end up within experimental error of my original 2643 px number. So, I am confident that this is the correct answer.
What I have tried
Here are the things I have tried to improve the focal length result.

Use of multiple softwares. I have tried the camera manufacturer's software (DepthAI), my own OpenCV implementation, and the MATLAB Camera Calibrator App. All three give me the same result.
Use of high quality boards. I have tried with two different boards from calib.io, as well as one I printed myself. Again, similar results from each.
I have good lighting with no glare, and clear corners.
My lens is focused well at my application's working distance, and I take images at roughly this working distance.
I have lots of angled images, since foreshortening is important for focal length.
I have used as few as 10-15 and as many as 100 images.

Below is an example of my distribution of data to give an idea of the poses I am using.

Questions
Here are some questions I have.

What is the best way to capture data to ensure an accurate focal length?
Is there anything about my process that raises any flags or questions?
Could my camera's construction (ie: cheap M12 lens) be contributing here?
Is the accuracy I am chasing reasonable for an OpenCV-based calibration with a pinhole camera?
What else can be done to further reduce the re-projection error?

Minimal Example
Here is a minimal example using OpenCV.
from pathlib import Path

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load images.
calib_images_path = Path("calibration_images")
image_files = list(calib_images_path.glob("*.png"))
images = [cv2.imread(str(image_file)) for image_file in image_files]

# Define the ChArUco board parameters.
charuco_size = (17, 24)
square_length = 30  # mm
marker_length = 22  # mm
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_1000)
charuco_board = cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard(
    size=charuco_size,
    squareLength=square_length,
    markerLength=marker_length,
    dictionary=aruco_dict,
)

# Detect ChArUco corners.
all_charuco_corners = []
all_charuco_ids = []
for image_file in image_files:
    # Grayscale image.
    image = cv2.imread(str(image_file))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Marker detection.
    corners, ids, rejected = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict)

    # Interpolation and refinement.
    if ids is not None and len(ids) > 0:
        cv2.aruco.refineDetectedMarkers(gray, charuco_board, corners, ids, rejected)

        retval, charuco_corners, charuco_ids = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(
            markerCorners=corners, markerIds=ids, image=gray, board=charuco_board
        )

        if retval > 0:
            all_charuco_corners.append(charuco_corners)
            all_charuco_ids.append(charuco_ids)

# Initial camera matrix and distortion coefficients.
expected_focal_length_px = 2642.9410561219647
image_size = gray.shape[::-1]
initial_camera_matrix = np.array(
    [
        [expected_focal_length_px, 0, image_size[0] / 2],
        [0, expected_focal_length_px, image_size[1] / 2],
        [0, 0, 1],
    ]
)
initial_dist_coeffs = np.zeros((5, 1))

# Camera calibration.
image_size = gray.shape[::-1]
ret, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.aruco.calibrateCameraCharuco(
    charucoCorners=all_charuco_corners,
    charucoIds=all_charuco_ids,
    board=charuco_board,
    imageSize=image_size,
    cameraMatrix=initial_camera_matrix,
    distCoeffs=initial_dist_coeffs,
)


the difference might be due to lens distortion. in the "experiment", you probably don't compensate for that (would be hard to do anyway), while the calibration does give you that. you can try nailing down the distortion coefficients to 0 with flags CALIB_FIX_K1,..., CALIB_FIX_K6. see what that does to the calibration.

everything you've done looks good. you can definitely expect better than those 5% difference. the repro error might be further reduced by transforming the images from gamma-compressed to linear. on the opencv forum there are people who do camera calibration for a living, also with high accuracy goals. might be worth browsing.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the advice! I tried using zero distortion coefficients, and I get a very similar result, though 5-10 px better. To me, this indicates there might be some small dependence there, but maybe there is a larger source of error somewhere in how I'm taking the data. Appreciate the pointer to the forum - I will make a post there and do some browsing.

There are a few factors at play here.

Focal length specifications on lenses will always only be "approximate". Specifically in the case of a M12 lens, focal length usually changes slightly with focus when the lens is screwed in and out of its threaded holder.
I would also not expect the pixel size specification to be accurate to more than 5%, especially not in uncontrolled temperature environment.
The focal length will often be correlated with distortion parameters. I.e. focal length may be smaller than nominal and distortion estimated to compensate for that.

Calib.io has the Calibrator program, which lets you investigate whether such parameter correlations exist, and lets you obtain a best fit linear camera model, estimating an "effective focal length" comparable to what you achieve experimentally.
Further, Calibrator lets you analyse whether the remaining rpe is due to un-modelled lens behaviour (bad), or only due to unbiased image noise (harmless).

Thanks for the suggestions. I have just purchased this software, and hopefully I will learn some things from using it and looking at the correlations.
